# Alternate Package for npm 'fs' to readfile sync

Tags: reactjs, npm, fs

I tried to read file sync from react Application using 'fs component' as of now **npm** had removed the **fs** component so I am unable to download the component

Later on I downloaded 'read-file' package to read file  -->However It Again depends on 'fs' package

Could anyone please let me know the alternative package to readfile using react js

Answer (score 0):

"fs" is a native module inside of Node.js which is why you can't download it from NPM and other modules you found on NPM are dependent on it (they are wrappers). You can download a "react-native" file-system from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-filesystem if you are working in react-native. If you are working in "react" (not react-native) you should not be accessing the file system directly, instead using a call to a web server, the browser cache or external resource to do any file system writes.

Comment: Hi @SteveB  
Thanks for your response my requirement is to read file async with utf18 format.

I am using adobe E-Sign API --> In this module each  and every model is dependent on fs native module.

I tried using  below modules but none of the modules were worked moreover  below components dependent on fs module . I am unable to call file-system methods because it internally depends on 'fs'

'
        var filesystem = require('file-system');
        var read = require('read-file');
'

Could you please help me from where I can download the fs component

Comment: @RajeshAkshith, can you post some code to help me understand where this read is taking place or what specific modules you are using? Are you reading files from a server or is the user browsing and selecting a file on their local computer?

Comment: @RajeshAkshith none of the code you posted has to do with React. You can edit your original question with the code and then you'll be able to format it. Is this server side or client side? Also do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

```
var AdobeSignSdk = require('adobe-sign-sdk');  
var fs = require('graceful-fs');  
var path = require('path');
var filesystem = require('file-system'); 
var read = require('read-file');  
var DIR_NAME = "C:/dev/mywork/hello/";                         
var FILE_NAME = "Userinfo.pdf"; 
var absoluteFilePath = path.join(DIR_NAME,FILE_NAME);
var buffer = fs.readFileSync(absoluteFilePath);
```

@steveb  Please find the above code
My requirement is to read the pdf sync and save the buffer In var variable

Comment: @SteveB  

Sorry I posted it as answer I am unable to post the code through comments